# How to use VR app without a controller/headset

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, google-vr

I'm using google VR with unity. for now i'm using a demo HelloVR scene. I'm very beginner, i don't have a VR headset or controller. Is there any way to test/run a vr app without vr headset and controller. I was expecting it to atleast move the view around in scene but nothing happens even moving device in any direction

Comment: How will you use the VR camera without a VR device? You could manually rotate/move the camera with keyboard keys.

Comment: Thanks @Saif, issue is sorted  in Build Settings -> Player Settings -> XR Settings i was selecting wrong VR SDK. Selecting cardboard and installing google card board app solved issue. my app appeared in home screen of cardboard app, from which i started app and it was working good. I was able to move the scene and interact with object using central white dot.

Answer (score 0):

For google cardboard you just use your smartphone, need nothing else needed to test, for real use you must have cardboard googles (can be made by yourself).